# Disable live chat option if agents are not online

Tags: liveagent, chat, offline

I need to disable the live chat option when all agents are offline.

I used `liveagent.showWhenOnline` and `liveagent.showWhenOffline` methods in the controller.

```
liveagent.showWhenOnline('button_id', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_button_id'));

liveagent.showWhenOffline('button_id', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_button_id'));
```

`liveagent_button_online_button_id` and `liveagent_button_offline_button_id` are referring to the element ids of corresponding div.

The functionality is working fine. But need to refresh the page and it takes some time to display/disable the button.

What can be the reason for this delay in response time?

Thank You!